# Assign database permissions to a server role

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Is it possible to grant database access to a user-defined server role?

My login *test-login* has the server role *myServerRole*. I have set up the table-level permissions:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON [dbo].[ConfigSettings] TO [myServerRole];
```

but *test-login* cannot connect to the database:

```
USE [MyTestDb]

Msg 916, Level 14, State 2, Line 1
The server principal "test-login" is not able to access the database "MyTestDb" under the current security context.
```

Background:
In our system we have many databases, 1 per customer, all with a similar structure. Each database contains a *ConfigSettings* table.

I want to allow a particular application full read/write access to this table only.

I know I could do this by creating a database user for this login in each database, and then granting permission to that database user. But it feels like I could save a few lines of code if could assign permissions directly to the user-defined server role.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MS Sql Server link a database level role to a server level role](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/305908/ms-sql-server-link-a-database-level-role-to-a-server-level-role)

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is not possible. According to [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/305908/ms-sql-server-link-a-database-level-role-to-a-server-level-role), server roles are only intended for server-level permissions.

Comment: Correct. If you wanted to share a server level permission to multiple database Users, then you can map a User of each database to the same Login who has that permission provisioned. But you're trying to essentially do the opposite, which is provision database level permissions to a Login, so you don't have to repeat yourself for each User of each database. Unfortunately, as far as I know (even after almost a year later), nothing has changed since I originally wrote that answer.